# Login Throttling and blocking all IP addresses

Tags: php, security, throttling, ip-blocking

I must throttle the login and I want to block all the IPs if a large scale failed attempts is coming in. How can I achieve that using the below code? If the below code is not good enough, please inform of a good tutorial on this matter.

```
<?php
$throttle = array(1 => 1, 10 => 2, 1000 => 'captcha');
$getfailedq = 'SELECT MAX(attempted) AS attempted FROM failed_logins';
$getfailed = $muc->prepare($getfailedq);
$getfailed->execute();
if ($getfailed->rowCount() > 0) {
    $row = $getfailed->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $latest_attempt = (int) date('U', strtotime($row['attempted']));
    $getfailedq = 'SELECT Count(*) AS failed FROM failed_logins WHERE attempted > Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 15 minute)';
    $getfailed = $muc->prepare($getfailedq);
    $getfailed->execute();
    if ($getfailed->rowCount() > 0) {
        $row = $getfailed->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $failed_attempts = (int) $row['failed'];
        krsort($throttle);
        foreach ($throttle as $attempts => $delay) {
            if ($failed_attempts > $attempts) {
                if (is_numeric($delay)) {
                    $remaining_delay =  time() - $latest_attempt + $delay;
                    echo 'You must wait ' . $remaining_delay . ' seconds before your next login attempt';
                } else {
                    echo "captcha";
                }
                break;
            }
        }        
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why exactly are you binding parameters, when neither of your queries have ANY parameters in them?

Comment: that's a good question, thanks, fixed the queries

Comment: `if ($getfailed->rowCount() > 0) {` this will always be true so your first query is pointless

Comment: @cmorrissey, right, how should I fix this?

Comment: max() will ALWays return a row, so the rowcount can never be zero. you have to fetch that max() value and test it directly.

Comment: you mean like this: $row= $MAX->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly pseudo code, based on your example. You could add an `ip` field to your `failed_logins` table, along with creating a new table named `blocked_logins`.

```
<?php

// get users IP address
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// find out if user has already been blocked
$getblockedq = 'SELECT ip FROM blocked_logins WHERE ip = :ip';
$getblocked = $muc->prepare($getblockedq);
$getblocked->execute(array(':ip' => $ip));
$total = $getblocked->fetchColumn();

if ($total > 0) {
    // user is blocked, do not proceed
}

// find number of failed logins within past 15 mins
$getfailedq = 'SELECT Count(*) AS failed FROM failed_logins WHERE ip = :ip AND attempted > Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 15 minute)';
$getfailed = $muc->prepare($getfailedq);
$getfailed->execute(array(':ip' => $ip));
$total = $getfailed->fetchColumn();

if ($total <= 2) {
    // looks good, attempt to login
} elseif ($total <= 10) {
    // you must wait x seconds...
} elseif ($total <= 1000) {
    // display captcha
} else {
    // block user
}
```

This should at least get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you but I get this error 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetchColumn()

Comment: @Serjio sorry, this is just pseudo code intended for logic, not syntax. Try it this way: `$getblocked->fetchColumn();` I've updated my example.